# « Y a-t-il des » ou « y a-t-ils des » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, interrogative, sujet

Quel est le meilleur moyen de dire ça en français ?

Selon mes recherches sur le réseau informatique, les deux formes sont également acceptées parmi les francophones natifs, mais peut-être s'agit-il d'une règle du choix sociolinguistique ou cognitif ?

Answer (score 12):

Non, une seule forme est acceptable : *Y a-t-il*, qui est juste la forme interrogative de *Il y a*. Dans cet usage, *il* ne se rapporte pas à une personne, mais à un état général.

Dans cette forme impersonnelle, on ne dit jamais <s>il y ont</s>, ni même <s>ils y ont</s>.

> Il y a des étoiles dans le ciel.
>
> Y a-t-il des étoiles dans le ciel ?

Cela vient de la conjugaison du verbe **avoir**.

Dans la forme personnelle, on peut s'exprimer au pluriel :

> Ils ont été à Marseille ; y ont-ils vu une sardine dans le vieux port ?

... Forme correcte (mais tout le monde sait qu'il n'y a pas de sardines dans le port de Marseille).

Vous pourrez trouver les détails sur la forme **il y a** [sur le tlfi, à Il](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/il), forme atone, B tournure impersonnelle, 5 avec verbes attributif, et c). (ouf).

Comment: Je pense que ce n'est pas pareil, car _Ils y ont vu une sardine_ amène _Il y a vu une sardine_ (y = dans le port), qui n'est pas le même **il** qu'avec _Il y a une sardine_ Et la question portait sur le _Il y a_ qu'il n'y a pas de _ils y ont_, dont j'invitais à ne pas confondre avec le _Ils y ont_ qui a _Il y a_, mais différemment. On le voit bien, non ?

Comment: Voilà, j'ai modifié en essayant d'expliquer la forme il y a, et en supprimant le jamais.

Answer (score 7):

*Y a-t-il*, tout comme *il y a*, est une tournure qui utilise le pronom **impersonnel** *il*, celui-ci est toujours employé au singulier.

Answer (score 4):

Pour une affirmation, *Y a-t-il* se transforme en *il y a*. Il n'y a donc pas de "s" à *il*.

Comment: C’est **Y a-t-il**, avec deux traits d’union pour le **t** euphonique.

Comment: @Nicolas Barbulesco: tout à fait, un oubli de ma part.

Answer (score 4):

Non, c'est beaucoup plus simple que ça. On écrit toujours *y a‑t‑il*, *y a‑t‑ils* n'est pas possible en français. Le sujet est le pronom impersonnel *il*, singulier. Et il reste au singulier même quand *il y a des millions de fourmis*. C'est exactement comme en allemand (*es gibt*). Au contraire des tournures anglaise et grecque, où les *fourmis* sont le sujet.

Answer (score 0):

Selon [cet article](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/orthographe/y-a-t-il-orthographe/) :

> Règle 1 : on ajoute un « t » euphonique dans les formules
>   interrogatives pour faciliter la prononciation et éviter que deux
>   voyelles se suivent. Toutefois, si le verbe conjugué se finit par un «
>   t », alors il n’est pas nécessaire d’ajouter un « t » euphonique.
>
> Règle 2 : un « t » euphonique ajouté pour faciliter la liaison entre
>   deux voyelles est toujours entouré par des tirets. Ainsi, dans les
>   formules interrogatives de forme « y a-t-il », on n’ajoutera pas de
>   tiret entre « y » et « a » mais seulement entre « a » et « il » afin
>   d’encadrer le « t ». On écrira donc toujours « y a-t-il » et non « y a
>   t-il » ou « y-a-t-il ».